# use Phalcon \ Session \ Adapter \ Database as Database not found

Tags: php, phalcon

I need to update from PHP 7.3 to PHP 8.0 or PHP 8.1.

About composer.json php from ~ 7.3.0 to ^ 8.0, ext-phalcon from ^ 3.3.0 to 5.0.0 beta3 I think I have to update to

When I updated it, I found the following error.
"Class "Phalcon\Session\Adapter" not found"

I was using the following on my existing system.
use Phalcon \ Session \ Adapter \ Database as

I checked the following page
https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/ja-jp/upgrade

The following changes have been made.
Removed Phalcon\Session\Adapter - replaced by Phalcon\Session\Adapter\AbstractAdapter

I tried the following, but the error still appeared.「"Class "Phalcon\Session\Adapter" not found"」
use Phalcon\Session\Adapter\Database as Database;

How can I solve it?

Comment: P.S.    I confirmed that use Phalcon \ Session \ Adapter; was used in \ vendor \ phalcon \ incubator \ Library \ Phalcon \ Session \ Adapter \ Database.php and an error occurred here.
Is it correct to recognize that there is no version compatible with Phalcon 5 for phalcon \ incubator?
What should i do?

Comment: composer.json　Change before　  "php": "~7.3.0",  "ext-phalcon": "^3.3.0",  "phalcon/incubator": "^3.3.0",

Comment: After change  "php": "^8.0",  "ext-phalcon": "5.0.0beta3",  "phalcon/incubator": "^2.0",　　　　　So far, we have changed as follows. Isn't the change in the phalcon / incubator version wrong?