# About phalcon / incubator that can be used with phalcon 5.0.0 beta3

Tags: php, phalcon

I need to update from PHP 7.3 to PHP 8.0 or PHP 8.1.

About composer.json php from ~ 7.3.0 to ^ 8.0, ext-phalcon from ^ 3.3.0 to 5.0.0 beta3 I think I have to update to

I'm looking for a phalcon / incubator that can be used with phalcon 5.0.0 beta3 but couldn't find it.

The latest of phalcon / incubator seemed to be v4.0.0-alpha.7.

I tried using phalcon / incubator (v2.0.10) that was automatically installed by "composer require phalcon / incubator".
I get the following error and cannot proceed
[use Phalcon \ Session \ Adapter \ Database as Database not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72166491/use-phalcon-session-adapter-database-as-database-not-found)

There is no phalcon / incubator that can be used with phalcon 5.0.0 beta3 yet, will it be made in the future?

What should i do?

Comment: `will it be made in the future?` - if it will not be abandoned - yes, it will.

Comment: Show your composer.json . If some package does not support PHP8, you can't do anything about it, unless making own fork and fixing it

Answer (score 0):

I would firstly take a look at the [phalcon/incubator-*](https://github.com/phalcon?q=incubator-&type=all&language=&sort=) packages as they seem yo be more uptodate and check for phal-5 support on the different branches.

Failing that you could install the package with --ignore-platform-req=ext-phalcon.

Then you would need to do some ugly hacks to make it work.

A lot of classes have been moved, take a look here.
https://docs.phalcon.io/5.0/en/upgrade

```php
include_once 'phalcon-4-to-5-upgrade-helper.php'
```

```php
// filename : phalcon-4-to-5-upgrade-helper.php



// v4 ->    v5

namespace Phalcon {

    // Phalcon\Cache    Phalcon\Cache\Cache
    class Cache extends Cache\Cache { }

    // Phalcon\Collection   Phalcon\Support\Collection
    class Collection extends Support\Collection { }

    // Phalcon\Config   Phalcon\Config\Config
    class Config extends Config\Config { }

    // Phalcon\Container    Phalcon\Container\Container
    class Container extends Container\Container { }

    // Phalcon\Crypt    Phalcon\Encryption\Crypt
    class Crypt extends Encryption\Crypt { }

    // Phalcon\Debug    Phalcon\Support\Debug
    class Debug extends Support\Debug { }

    // Phalcon\Di   Phalcon\Di\Di
    class Di extends Di\Di { }

    // Phalcon\Escaper  Phalcon\Html\
    class Escaper extends Html\Escaper { }

    //Phalcon\Exception Removed
    class Exception extends \Exception { }

    // Phalcon\Filter   Phalcon\Filter\Filter
    class Filter extends Filter\Filter { }

    // Phalcon\Helper   Removed in favor of Phalcon\Support\Helper
    class Helper extends Support\Helper { }

    // Phalcon\Loader   Phalcon\Autoload\Loader
    class Loader extends Autoload\Loader { }

    // Phalcon\Logger   Phalcon\Logger\Logger
    class Logger extends Logger\Logger { }

    // Phalcon\Kernel   Removed
    class Kernel
    {
        public static function preComputeHashKey( string $key )
        {
            return hash('sha256', $key);
        }
    }

    // Phalcon\Registry Phalcon\Support\Registry
    class Registry{ 
        // cannot extend final class  \Phalcon\Support\Registry  or use class_alias as the class isn't user defined (it's a extension defined class))
    }
    // Phalcon\Security Phalcon\Encryption\Security
    class Security extends Encryption\Security { }

    // Phalcon\Text Removed in favor of Phalcon\Support\Helper
    class Text extends Support\Helper { }

    // Phalcon\Url  Phalcon\Mvc\Url
    class Url extends Mvc\Url { }

    // Phalcon\Validation   Phalcon\Filter\Validation
    class Validation extends Filter\Validation { }

    // Phalcon\Version  Phalcon\Support\Version
    class Version extends Support\Version { }
}

namespace Phalcon\Validation {
    interface ValidationInterface extends  \Phalcon\Filter\Validation\ValidationInterface {}
}

// Phalcon\Support\Helper didnt exist for me.

namespace Phalcon\Support {

    use Phalcon\Di\Injectable;

    class Helper extends Injectable
    {
        public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments)
        {
            return (new self())->helper->$name(...$arguments);
        }
    }
}
```